# Two sum algorithm variant - Optimization

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to compute the number of target values t in the interval [-10000,10000] (inclusive) such that there are distinct numbers x,y in the input file that satisfy x+y=t. I have the code which does work and would like to optimize it to run it faster.

Also, we'll count the sum **t** only once. If there are two x,y pairs that add to 55, you will only increment the result once. Input numbers could be both positive and negative integers.

```
public static int Calculate(int start, int finish, HashSet<long> numbers)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int sum = start; sum <= finish; sum++)
    {
        foreach (long n in numbers)
        {
            if (numbers.Contains(sum - n) && n != (sum - n))
            {
                result++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is an assignment and I completed it with full marks. My code is taking like 30 minutes to run against the data set of 1 Million numbers. I tried to think a way to optimize my code, but couldn't get to the right thought and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Optimizing working code is off topic on here. This site is for fixing broken code. You can try codereview.stackexchange for optimizing code.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seems to be a better place for this.

Comment: Sure, thq. I'll repost it there and close it here.

Comment: Sometimes optimization means using a completely different algorithm, which is in the scope of this site. This may not be so common in the [c#] tag, but is one of the main purposes of the [algorithm] tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is advised to post in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @deathismyfriend This site is not only for fixing broken code.

Comment: I honestly think this question is fine right where it is.

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the input?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes. I tried that using List<long> instead of HashSet<long>. But, I couldn't get a better running time.

Comment: Ok. Are you allowed to hash different sums that can be generated from the sorted list?

Comment: are there any bounds on the input? positive, negative, signed 64 bit integer?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Input numbers are both positive, negative and include duplicate entries.

Comment: another question :) are you supposed to count only distinct sums between `start` and `finish` that are achievable with `numbers` or do `2 + 3` and `1 + 4` get counted twice?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, we'll add 5 only once. I added that constrain to the question for more clarity.

Comment: then how did you get full marks for it ? :) Isn't it counting duplicate sums?

Comment: @גלעדברקן My first **for** loop will keep track of the sum (t) value I am verifying for and once I find that, the inner llop will break out of the loop and the sum value will be incremented making sure that I only increment the result once for each sum value, t.

Comment: you said the input includes **duplicate** entries, but the function declares numbers to be `HashSet<long>`, i.e. no duplicates. how that could be? or you are eliminating them while populating that set before calling the function? also, when you say 1M numbers, do you mean `numbers.Count`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, I removed duplicates before populating the `HashSet<long>` and 1M numbers is the input size. My input size after removing duplicates is just couple of hundreds less than 1M.

Comment: I'm puzzled: before trying to implement and test a more efficient algorithm, I first simply used the implementation stated in the problem. On my PC this takes about 20 seconds (in debugmode, C#) for 1M (10^6) random input-numbers in the range -int.MaxValue .. + int.MaxValue, and searching sums in [-10k..+10k]. I varied various "bounds" for number generation and sum searches and always get results back in seconds, not minutes. What am I missing in the problem where you say it takes 30 MINUTES.

Comment: @BertteVelde I did the same test and got ~6sec (release mode). However, then I tried getting 1M longs from a binary file (any file with size > 8MB), and the algorithm didn't complete (at least I had no nervous to wait more than a few minutes :-)  I guess this is happening when the algorithm hits the worst case (no early exit from the inner loop). For comparison, the algorithm I posted takes 75ms in the first case and 24ms in the second.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, I see.  You provided an elegant approach with recursion. However, I believe it can be done even faster. I'll put up an alternative "answer" shortly.

Comment: Review of functional code is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Such questions belong on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

There's a classic linear-time algorithm for finding two numbers in a sorted array `A` that sum to a specified target. Initialize `i` to the first index and `j` to the last. If `A[i] + A[j]` is less than the target, increase `i`. If it's less than the target, decrease `j`. Stop when `i >= j`.

Sorting the array with a comparison sort is asymptotically costlier than hashing, but this setup cost is negligible, and the improved memory layout of the array will yield a significant performance increase.

To optimize further, you can invert the loop structure and, for each number in the array, figure out what combinations it makes.

To optimize further still (at least asymptotically), use a Fourier transform to convolve (sections of) the array with each other. Since your numbers are distinct, I'm not convinced that this will be an improvement in practice.

Comment: What is the name of this algorithm?

Comment: @Hoten I think it's folklore.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look following solution:

```
    public static int Calculate(int start, int finish, List<long> numbers)
    {
        HashSet<long> resultSet = new HashSet<long>();            
        for (int indexA = 0; indexA < numbers.Count - 1; indexA++)
        {
            for (int indexB = indexA+1; indexB < numbers.Count; indexB++)
            {
                long tempSum = numbers[indexA] + numbers[indexB];
                if ((tempSum >= start) && (tempSum <= finish))
                {
                    resultSet.Add(tempSum);
                }
            }
        }
        return resultSet.Count();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you do differently, why you do it and what effect it has?

Comment: Yes, idea is finding x and y in a set of numbers which must be equal to the number **t**. 
Number **t** is any number between **start** and **finish**.
In order to avoid duplicate target sums I use **HashSet**

Comment: Big O notation of that logic is less than: O(n^2)

Comment: The logic is slightly off. This is assuming that `start` and `finish` are indexes of `numbers` - which is not the case.

Comment: Noo, no no... :) Please read code carefully... 
**Start** and **finish** are not indexes. They are possible **t** values.
 **t** might be: **Start**, **Start+1**,  **...**, **Start+n**, **...**, **finish-1**, **finish**

Comment: Intel **Core i5-2500K** (Quad core) does **83,000 MIPS** (million instructions per second)
Logic's **Big O** is: **O(n^2);**
**Big O** equals 1 trillion If **n** (quantity of numbers in the list) is 1 million;
So **Core i5** requires: 1000000000000 **/** 83000000000 = **12.05 Seconds**

Comment: I think you have it backwards - `numbers` contains the possible results. `start` and `finish` are a contiguous block of numbers that we need to check. So, if `start=1`, `finish=4`, and `numbers = [3,4,5]`, the result would be `3,4,5` (1 + 2, 1+3, 1+4) [and ignored: 2+1, 2+2, 2+3]

Comment: Actually - I think the OP's code is *slightly* broken. The number he generates for `sum` (x) is taken from start <= x <= finish (which supports my comment above). However, then we check for `y` by checking if it's within `numbers` - which supports your solution. However, doing *both* might not always give the correct result, but it seems for the test case he used, it did work. However, it is not *always* the case. @PushCode can you verify this? Are (x,y) taken from `start` - `finish`, or from `numbers` ?

Comment: 1) **Start** <= **t** <= **finish**;
2) **t** = **x** + **y**;
3) **x** and **y** are distinct numbers from the list;

Comment: @VitaliDonghvani Sorry - you're right - I had a brain fart.. `t` is indeed taken from the `start` and `finish` - I read the question completely opposite.

Comment: @VitaliDonghvani Running time is **O(n^2)** which is almost same as what I have.

Comment: You use **HashSet<T>.Contains Method**, whenever you perform a lookup, the Comparer code would have to be executed on every key to check if there is a match. This would be extra O(n) in your logic

Answer (score 0):

This code can be optimized a lot simply by using a better datastructure. Use a `SortedSet` instead of a `HashSet`. Now the code can easily be optimized:

```
public static int calculate(int start , int finish , SortedSet<long> numbers){
    int count = 0;

    for(long l in numbers){
        SortedSet<long> sub = numbers.GetViewBetween(l - start , l - finish);
        count += sub.Count() - (sub.Contains(l) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Note that this code might not compile, since i haven't used c# since quite some time. You can even further optimize this code by simply ignoring values, which fulfill `number.min() + n > finish` or `number.max() + n < start`.

Comment: I'm not versed in C# - how is this code avoiding counting duplicate target sums? I think the question asks for the number of distinct sums achievable between `start` and `finish`.

Comment: in `x + y = t` only `x` and `y` must be distinct. or atleast that's how i understood the question, but i couldn't find anything that prohibits multiple appeareances of the same `t`. If you mean "how does this code avoid `x = y`, this is ensured by ` - (sub.Contains(l) ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: `the number of target values t in the interval [-10000,10000]` means if I see 55 twice as an achievable sum, I only count it once. Does it not?

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes, you should count 55 only once.

Comment: so how does your code guarantee that the next `l` won't count another 55?

Comment: mathematically it doesn't, since there's nothing mentioned like "unique target-values", but maybe op implied this

Comment: op's code, which he said he received full marks for, is only counting distinct sums

Comment: @גלעדברקן it doesn't at all, since this was not a constraint in the question, but just mentioned by OP in a comment.

Comment: @PushCode, you should add this constraint to the question, so far this is **not** clear

Answer (score 0):

With credits to David Eisenstat, putting it all together into action for the concrete case:

```
public static int Calculate(this IEnumerable<long> input, int minSum, int maxSum)
{
    var sortedSet = input.AsParallel().Distinct().OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
    for (int lo = 0, hi = sortedSet.Length - 1; lo < hi;)
    {
        var sum = sortedSet[lo] + sortedSet[hi];
        if (sum < minSum) lo++;
        else if (sum > maxSum) hi--;
        else return 1 + Calculate(sortedSet, lo, hi, minSum, (int)sum - 1) + Calculate(sortedSet, lo, hi, (int)sum + 1, maxSum);
    }
    return 0;
}
private static int Calculate(long[] sortedSet, int lo, int hi, int minSum, int maxSum)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int targetSum = minSum; targetSum <= maxSum; targetSum++)
    {
        for (int i = lo, j = hi; i < j;)
        {
            var sum = sortedSet[i] + sortedSet[j];
            if (sum < targetSum) i++;
            else if (sum > targetSum) j--;
            else { count++; break; }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**EDIT** even better:

```
public static int Calculate(this IEnumerable<long> input, int minSum, int maxSum)
{
    if (minSum > maxSum) return 0;
    var sortedSet = input.AsParallel().Distinct().OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
    return CalculateCore(sortedSet, 0, sortedSet.Length - 1, minSum, maxSum);
}
private static int CalculateCore(long[] sortedSet, int lo, int hi, int minSum, int maxSum)
{
    if (minSum > maxSum) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (lo < hi)
    {
        var sum = sortedSet[lo] + sortedSet[hi];
        if (sum < minSum) lo++;
        else if (sum > maxSum) hi--;
        else
        {
            count++;
            if (minSum == maxSum) break;
            if (sum - minSum <= maxSum - sum)
            {
                count += CalculateCore(sortedSet, lo, hi - 1, minSum, (int)sum - 1);
                minSum = (int)sum + 1;
                lo++;
            }
            else
            {
                count += CalculateCore(sortedSet, lo + 1, hi, (int)sum + 1, maxSum);
                maxSum = (int)sum - 1;
                hi--;
            }
        };
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the running time still **O(n^2)**?

Comment: @PushCode  I think it is **O(N*M)**

Comment: On my laptop (of course build in release mode and run outside VS) it completes for less than a second for 1M numbers

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can essentially be done in O(NlogN), where N is the number of points to construct the sums with, and assuming M, the range of sums-to-find is small in comparison.

```
private int CalcSlide(int first, int last, HashSet<long> numbers)
{
  if (last < first)
    return 0;

  // Strategy:
  // running over the input numbers, in ordered fashion from below, we'll scan an "appropriate" sliding window
  // in that same collection to see if we find any sums that we didn't find before.
  // We start out with the lowest number as an "anchor" and determine the HIGHEST number that might be relevant,
  // i.e. that will not sum to beyond "last".
  // Saving that separately, for later use, we scan down until we sum (always with the "anchor") to below "first".
  //
  // We maintain the sums-to-be-found in a hash.
  // As soon as our scan hits a yet-to-be-found sum, we remove it from the hash and update first/last as appropriate.
  // Having completed this cycle we increase the anchor, redetermine the hightest relevant number to start a new scan,
  // (this redetermination starts at the saved previous value, walking down), and then we scan again.
  // Exits occur whever the obvious conditions are fullfilled: there's nothing left to search for, we've nothing left to scan.
  //
  // Time-complexity:
  // Given an input hash set we first construct a sorted array from that: O(nLogn)
  // The subsequent sliding-window-scan procedure is O(N) if we look at scnario's with N (the number of input points) being much larger
  // than the range of sums-to-find. More precisely the worst-case behaviour is O(N M logM), where M is the range of sums to find.
  // (It would be somewhat difficult to construct an scenario where we really have such "worst case behaviour").
  // 1. Obviously, the "outer loop" over the anchor is just "from 1 to N".
  // 2. Computing the upperbound of the scan, for each anchor again, is also linear: it just runs from N-1 down to the anchor
  //    (in separate strides for each anchor).
  // 3. The scan, at each round, is somewhat more complicated. It is potentially long - over all numbers down to the anchor.
  //    However, since all numbers are different (coming from a hashset), the scanwindow can never be larger than the range of sums (yet) to find.
  //    The worst-case behaviour is then O(N*MlogM), where the logM factor arises from having to search for a sum in the hashSet of sums.
  //    Of course, as we find "some" sums on the way, both the search-in-sumHashSet diminishes and the scanwindow gets smaller whenever we find
  //    the current "first" or "last".

  int sumCountOriginal = last - first + 1;

  // Get a sorted array from the provided numbers.
  long[] sortedSet = new long[this.HNumbers.Count];
  int j = 0;
  foreach (long value in HNumbers)
    sortedSet[j++] = value;
  Array.Sort(sortedSet);

  // Create a (relatively small) HashSet from the sums sought.
  // This serves to easily remove items that we find, and then verify if there are any left.
  HashSet<int> HSums = new HashSet<int>();
  for (int sum = first; sum <= last; ++sum)
    HSums.Add(sum);

  int N = sortedSet.Length;

  int jLow = 0;
  int jScanStart = sortedSet.Length - 1;

  while (HSums.Count > 0)
  {
    long xLow = sortedSet[jLow];
    long xScan = sortedSet[jScanStart];

    // decrease jScanStart to get maxSum or less.
    while (jScanStart > jLow + 1 && xScan + xLow > last)
      xScan = sortedSet[--jScanStart];

    // scan until we get below minSum.
    int jScan = jScanStart;
    while (jScan > jLow && xLow + xScan >= first)
    {
      int sum = (int)(xLow + xScan);
      if (HSums.Contains(sum))
      {
        HSums.Remove(sum);

        if (sum == last)
          while (last >= first && !HSums.Contains(last))
            last--;

        if (sum == first)
          while (first <= last && !HSums.Contains(first))
            first++;

        if (last < first)
          return sumCountOriginal;
      }

      xScan = sortedSet[--jScan];
    } // scan

    // next xLow.
    if (++jLow == N - 1 || jScanStart <= jLow)
      return sumCountOriginal - HSums.Count;

  } // there are still unresolved sums.

  // unexpected fall-thru - we should never get here.
  return sumCountOriginal - HSums.Count;
}
```